# Error handling when using Observable.flatMap

Tags: rx-java2

There is a sample program below that replicates my issue.

Issue:

1. Apply the `flatMap` transformation to some `Observable`
2. Subscribe to the aforementioned `Observable`, store the subscription somewhere
3. Dispose of the aforementioned subscription before the `Observable` terminates naturally
4. In an `Observable` returned by the mapper function, raise an `Exception`
5. Flatmap operator doesn't know how to handle the `Exception`, raises it, program crashes/quits

Preferred/expected behaviour:

- The error should be propagated to my `onError` handler instead of crashing the program when `RxJavaPlugins#onError` is invoked

The culprit is the snippet of code below, found in `ObservableFlatMap`. The issue is that once the parent has been disposed of, invocations to `addThrowable` return false. Thus, the error is never propagated down to `onError`.

```
@Override
public void onError(Throwable t) {
  if (parent.errors.addThrowable(t)) {
      if (!parent.delayErrors) {
          parent.disposeAll();
      }
      done = true;
      parent.drain();
  } else {
      RxJavaPlugins.onError(t);
  }
}
```

What can I do in this situation? I need an operator that acts like `flatMap` and propagates errors down to my `onError` handler instead of crashing my program.

This is a real scenario with an Android app of mine. Subscriptions are automatically disposed when the user exits a window/activity and exceptions may be raised after disposal due to `InterruptedIOException`s.

Code to replicate issue

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler((throwable)->{
      System.out.println("Please don't come through here");
      throwable.printStackTrace();
    });
    Disposable disposable = Observable.just(1)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .flatMap((item)->{
          return Observable.just(1)
              .doOnNext((arg)->Thread.sleep(1000))
              .doOnNext((arg)->{
                throw new RuntimeException("Error");
              });
        })
        .subscribe(System.out::println, (throwable)->{
          System.out.println("Please come through here");
          throwable.printStackTrace();
        });
    Thread.sleep(500);
    disposable.dispose();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }

}
```

Execution output

```
Please don't come through here
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
  at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:349)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$InnerObserver.onError(ObservableFlatMap.java:573)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onError(ObservableDoOnEach.java:119)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onError(ObservableDoOnEach.java:119)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onNext(ObservableDoOnEach.java:99)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableScalarXMap$ScalarDisposable.run(ObservableScalarXMap.java:248)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableJust.subscribeActual(ObservableJust.java:35)
  at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10903)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
  at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10903)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
  at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10903)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.subscribeInner(ObservableFlatMap.java:162)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.onNext(ObservableFlatMap.java:139)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.onNext(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:58)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableScalarXMap$ScalarDisposable.run(ObservableScalarXMap.java:248)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableJust.subscribeActual(ObservableJust.java:35)
  at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10903)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
  at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:38)
  at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:26)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
  at Main.lambda$null$1(Main.java:18)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onNext(ObservableDoOnEach.java:95)
  ... 22 more
```

Expected/preferred output

```
Please come through here
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error
  at Main.lambda$null$2(Main.java:19)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onNext(ObservableDoOnEach.java:95)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onNext(ObservableDoOnEach.java:103)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableScalarXMap$ScalarDisposable.run(ObservableScalarXMap.java:248)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableJust.subscribeActual(ObservableJust.java:35)
  at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10903)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
  at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10903)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
  at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10903)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.subscribeInner(ObservableFlatMap.java:162)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.onNext(ObservableFlatMap.java:139)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.onNext(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:58)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableScalarXMap$ScalarDisposable.run(ObservableScalarXMap.java:248)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableJust.subscribeActual(ObservableJust.java:35)
  at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10903)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
  at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:38)
  at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:26)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())` before `flatMap`. When you `dispose` your interrupting thread that produces flat map observables which breaks the whole subscription. To fix this your should specify subscription after or inside `flatMap` or observe it in a different thread.

Working example:

```
RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler((throwable) -> {
        System.out.println("Please don't come through here");
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    });
    Disposable disposable = Observable.just(1)
            .flatMap((item) -> {
                return Observable.just(1)

                        .doOnNext((arg) -> Thread.sleep(1000))
                        .doOnNext((arg) -> {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("Error");
                        })
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
            })
            .subscribe(System.out::println,
                    (throwable) -> {
                        System.out.println("Please come through here");
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                    });
    Thread.sleep(500);
    disposable.dispose();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Hey sorry about the late reply, I was busy with uni this week. I got pretty confused about why this worked and started debugging it a bit, it looks like your solution works because it completely skips using `ObservableFlatMap`  because my sample source `Observable` is a `ScalarCallable`. I guess for optimization purposes, `Observable#flatMap` uses `ObservableScalarXMap#scalarXMap` instead of `ObservableFlatMap`. If you change `Observable.just(1)` to `Observable.just(1, 2)` then the error still occurs.

Comment: As I sad before problem is not in optimization of `Observable#flatMap`, but in thread where you subscribe and observer. In your code interrupting main thread where program is running. Please check this one: `.flatMap((item)-> Observable.just(1, 2)
      .doOnNext((arg)->Thread.sleep(1000))
      .doOnNext((arg)->{
       throw new RuntimeException("Error");
      }).observeOn(Schedulers.computation()))` It should work

Comment: When you say "it should work" what do you mean? I plugged in your code and yes it prints out `Please come through here` but that's because the thread is never interrupted and `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error` is thrown by the Observable. Just so we're on the same page, I uploaded the code I ran [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/BG3hWZPK).

Comment: Maybe I can't understand correctly, but it correctly suspends inner thread so main thread where observable is running could handle it and successfully finish execution. But if you want interrupt main thread and handle some how exception, then I would say it is impossible. It is the  same to run some thing like this `public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  throw new RuntimeException("Error");
 }` there is no one who could handle this exception, since it is application thread